# nhibernate Operation could destabilize the runtime

Tags: nhibernate, proxy, medium-trust

Locally my site works, but at host I am getting the error:

"Operation could destabilize the runtime."

I am using nhibernate.
I am using the repository pattern.

```
[VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.]
   CategoryProxy..ctor() +6

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache) +86
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache) +230
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +67
   LinFu.DynamicProxy.ProxyFactory.CreateProxy(Type instanceType, IInterceptor interceptor, Type[] baseInterfaces) +20
   NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactory.GetProxy(Object id, ISessionImplementor session) +208

[HibernateException: Creating a proxy instance failed]
   NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactory.GetProxy(Object id, ISessionImplementor session) +306
```

Comment: Are you using Fluent?

Answer (score 1):

use Castle Dynamic Proxy

Comment: I am running 2.1.2GA, and opening up the sol'n shows that they are using dymaicproxy2 version 2.1.0.0, can't find that branch for it here: https://svn.castleproject.org/svn/castle/DynamicProxy

Comment: you can get the branch for Castle DP 2.1 here: https://svn.castleproject.org/svn/castle/tags/dynamicproxy-2.1.0/
But why do you need the code? Get the binary.

I also suggest getting version 2.2 beta (released today!), but at the moment, you'll have to build NHibernate ProxyFactoryFactory project yourself against this new version.

Comment: So, Castle DynamicProxy works in medium trust, and LinFu doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

This has happend to me before. Check if your code contains a long switch clause. 
from here: http://forums.asp.net/p/981415/1255521.aspx

Comment: nhibernate is huge, and it does have many switch statements which I am not going to modify :)